# How can I change the default app that opens when double tapping the screen of my Galaxy note with the S Pen?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note, notes

I would like to change the default behaviour of S Pen so that instead of using the (not so good) memo app from Samsung I can use the note taking app of my choice (right now [Papyrus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.steadfastinnovation.android.projectpapyrus&hl=en)).

How can I change the default behaviour of double tapping the screen with the S Pen while holding its side button to open my app of choice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use the app Pentastic for that.
https://galaxystore.samsung.com/detail/com.samsung.android.pentastic

I was actually looking for a way to disable this shortcut. This can be accomplished by combining the above with the app "Do Nothing".
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=i.donothing

Answer (score -2):

Get "S Note Helper" from Google Play Store

Comment: Would you mind to give some explanation how this answers the question? A link to the app would be fine, too.

Comment: There's no such app in the Play Store. Are you sure that's the name ?

Comment: Might be he meant [S Pen Helper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tushar.spen_helper). According to the screenshots, this can at least enable/disable launching the "default app". Not sure if it can configure the same -- I have no device to check with :)